# Tumblr - oauth_signature does not match expected value

Tags: oauth, tumblr, adonis.js

There are already topics on this topic, but I have not been able to solve the problem on my side.

I develop a driver of auth for **AdonisJS Ally** and **Tumblr**, I get this error after the callback. However, **oAuthToken**, **requestToken.oAuthTokenSecret** and **oAuthVerifier** are correct (at least, I think).

## The response is:

> error { statusCode: 401,   data: 'oauth_signature does not match
>   expected value' }

## The request token URL:

https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_consumer_key=Vv3XfKpkZAXAehLxk9h76cjPkUyq7iDnqMjmEKwqKrOriGSVoG&oauth_nonce=fd47a26a06ceb6ce20121bc98ac78a01&oauth_signature=Hkhvn1n5kgjg9P0IeKwvqKT9j3I%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1323327331&oauth_version=1.0

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var request = require("request");

var oauth ={
         consumer_key: "****************************", 
         consumer_secret: "****************************"
};
var url = 'https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token'
request.post({url:url, oauth:oauth}, function (e, r, body) {
    var temp1 = body.split("&");
   var auth_token=temp1[0].split("=")[1];
   var auth_secret=temp1[1].split("=")[1];
   var tokens=[auth_token,auth_secret];
    console.log(temp1)
    cb(undefined,{d:tokens});
})
```

this code worked to me, try this.
There is no proper documentation for tumblr, but from the doc what i understood is there are 3 ways to get authenticated in tumblr and receive auth_token and auth_token secret the above code might not work because there is change of auth_nonce and auth_signature and hence you receive the error as
*oauth_signature does not match expected value* so i would suggest to use my method to generate the auth_token and auth_token_secret. this code works without adding any signature and nonce

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: thank you for the advice. will definitely work on it.